# Declarar variable numerica de Python a partir de otra variable numericaé

Tags: python

¿Cómo puedo tomar el resultado de unas Variables en **Python**?

```
>>>b=input ('ingresa un numero') 2
#Variables Ejemplo
a=3
#si a es igual a 3 y b igual a 2
# entonces la multiplicacion de a*b es igual a "6"
a*b
#Resultado = "6"
6
#Quiero tomar el Resultado de "6" y multiplicarlo por "10" que es un numero Fijo
# EJEMPLO
6*10
```

¿Cómo puedo declarar el Numero "6" que es un número de un resultado muy variable y multiplicarlo por el número Fijo?

Comment: en el título de la pregunta debes indicar el problema exacto, pues así como esta no es claro en nada de lo que ocurre

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que haya entendido correctamente tu pregunta:

tu código quedaría así:

```
>>>b=input ('ingresa un numero') 2
a=3
resultado = a*b*10 #esto es igual a 3*2*10 = 60
```

Para declarar una variable en python tienes que utilizar `identificador = valor`